# How do I save the imageview created to camera roll?

Tags: android, qr-code

In the code below, you can see that I have created an imageview using a bitmap. What I want to know is how I can save an image of that imageview to my camera roll. Thanks!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.key_code_zoom);

title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accountTitleLarge);
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.keyCodeLarge);

Intent callingActivity = getIntent();
Bundle callingBundle = callingActivity.getExtras();
if (callingBundle != null) {
    String titleText = callingBundle.getString("title");
    byte[] bytes = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("bitmapbytes");
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    title.setText(titleText);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        supportFinishAfterTransition();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Photos are harder than expected since is a common task anyone tends to think it should be trivial, but it is not, quite long and tedious actually. I recommend you this library github.com/fabian7593/MagicalCamera is the best for taking photos, takes care of permissions, take the photo or choose it from the gallery, it will save it as a file in the device, it will also register it in the gallery, has another features but that should get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save an image in gallery, you must first get the bitmap and then save it.

```
private void imageToRoll(){
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image = imageView.getDrawingCache();  // Gets the Bitmap
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imageBitmap, imagTitle , imageDescription);  // Saves the image.
}
```

Also, set the permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I believe it will work but my emulated device is saying that my Virtual SD card is corrupted. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Try creating a new AVD as there seems to some problem with the SD card image. However, I would recommend you to test in a real device instead of an emulator.

Comment: I created.a new AVD and it's not working. I will try with a device later! Thanks!

Comment: Do you receive any error in the stacktrace? Or is it the corrupt SD card error?

Comment: Corrupt SD card error. I just started trying with a device.

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some code that will help you save the Image from the ImageView to your phone storage then the following code will help you

```
 public String getImageFromView() {

    imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    // this is the important code :)
    // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null
    imageview.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)); 

    imageview.layout(0, 0, imageview.getMeasuredWidth(), imageview.getMeasuredHeight());
    imageview.buildDrawingCache(true);

    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap b = imageview.getDrawingCache();
    String imgPath = getImageFilename();
    File file = new File(imgPath);

    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        ContentValues image = new ContentValues();
        image.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "NST");
        image.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
        image.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "App Image");
        image.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        image.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
        image.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);
        File parent = file.getParentFile();
        image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, parent.toString()
                .toLowerCase().hashCode());
        image.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, parent.getName()
                .toLowerCase());
        image.put(Images.Media.SIZE, file.length());
        image.put(Images.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri result = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imgPath;
    }
```

you will have to provide a file path `getImageFilename();`this function provides the path where the file is suppose to be stored. The `ContentValues` will be responsible to let the images be scanned in gallery.
Hope this helps.